# Why researchers use MATLAB based YALMIP or CasADi for MPC?

Tags: optimization, software, optimal-control

I was looking at various research papers and most of the researchers use CasADi, YALMIP, MPCTools to implement MPC. My question is "Why researchers use MATLAB based YALMIP or CasADi for MPC rather than using only built-in options like MATLAB, Simulink or the MPC Designer app?"

Comment: Did you check whether the external tools (YALMIP or CasADi) pre-date the built-in options?